# how to pass TxMongo lib the proper db name

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm right now using TxMongo lib as mongodb driver in python. To make a db connection, I need to do something like this:

```
mongo = yield ConnectionPool(mongodb_uri, ssl_context_factory=tls_ctx)

foo = mongo.foo  # `foo` database
test = foo.test  # `test` collection
```

So the problem is, what if the db name contains: `-` in its name??
The python will not interpret it correctly:

```
foo = mongo.foo-f  # `foo-f` database
test = foo.test  # `test` collection
```

The official doc says nothing about it.

(I CANNOT use `foo = mongo.'foo-f'`, nor

```
 foo = 'foo-f'
 foo_f = mongo.'foo-f'  # `foo-f` database`)
```

Comment: I can copy the db to another one which has no '-' in its name. But this solution might not be suitable for production use.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code

```
foo = mongo['foo-f']
```